# Javascript only temporarily changing

Tags: javascript, html, visibility, temporary

I'm trying to do a simple email validation and have a `<p>` and an `<img>` display once you are validated.  Unfortunately, the javascript is only changing the style(visibility) for a brief second, then it reverts back to invisible (the default). How do I get it to be permanent?

I have this code for the javascript:

```
    function submitEmail () {
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else {
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            //stop the loading symbol
            //code to handle the return of data
            if (xmlhttp.responseText == "Correct") {
                alert("WORKED!");//email uploaded successfully
            }
            else if (xmlhttp.responseText == "Duplicate") {
                //email already added
            }
            else {
                //server error
            }
        }
    }
    var email = document.getElementById("emailInput").value;
    xmlhttp.open("POST", "http://www.studiosbt.com/Stream/addEmailToListServe.php?", true);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    if (email != "" && email != "Email") {
        xmlhttp.send("email="+email);
    }
};
function subscribe(){
    //start the loading symbol
    var email = document.getElementById("emailInput").value;
    if (email != "" && email != "Email") {
        submitEmail();
        success();
    }
    else {
        alert("Input error!");//input error
    }
};
function success() {
    document.getElementById("checkBox").style.visibility = "visible";
    document.getElementById("thankYou").style.visibility = "visible";
};
function validateEmail() { 
var re = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
if (re.test(document.getElementById("emailInput").value)) {
    subscribe();
}
else {
    alert("Wrong!");
}
}
```

It works in the sense that it does display the checkBox and thankYou elements briefly, but they don't stay.  What do I do?

Here is the CSS code for the checkBox and thankYou elements:

```
#emailBox p{
color: white;
visibility: hidden;
}
#checkBox{
height: 25px;
width: 25px;
top: 45%;
right: 94%;
position: absolute;
visibility: hidden;
}
```

Finally, here is the html:

```
<body>

<div id="container">
<header>
    <h1>Header here</h1>
</header>
<div id="emailBox">
        <form name="emailform" id="emailform" onclick="return true;">
                    <input type="text" id="emailInput" class="emailcheck" tabindex="1" value="Email" onblur="if(this.value=='') {this.value='Email'; }" onfocus="if(this.value=='Email') { this.value='';}" name="email" autocomplete="off">

                    <input type="button" id="submit" class="emailcheck" value="Subscribe" onclick="javascript:validateEmail()">
        </form>
        <p id="thankYou">Thank you for subscribing!</p>
        <img src="Graphics/checkBox.png" id="checkBox"/>

</div>

</div>      
</body>
```

Comment: Please post a complete code example.

Comment: How is the validation done?

Comment: And what triggers the validation check? If it's a `<form>` submit event, or clicking a `<button>` or `<a>`, then it seems probable that a new page is being loaded.

Comment: where did you put this code in your html?  A script tag in the body?  In the header?  In a jquery onload?

Comment: The problem is not in the displayed code, show more code plz.

Comment: I edited it to add more code.

Comment: Show the HTML please (CSS too would probably help) --- scratch that... you need to create a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: Where do you make those two items invisible? Also, on what event does that Javascript run?

Comment: Try, `$("#checkBox").css("display", "block");` and `$("#thankYou").css("display", "block");`

Comment: You need to display where you are invoking validateemail and what other functions effect those controls.

Comment: Is `submitEmail()` causing a page reload? That would explain the momentary flash of visibility.

Comment: I am using CSS to make the thankYou and checkBox IDs "visibility: hidden" then I use the javascript to change it to visibile. The Javascript runs on the event onsubmit which is when the form gets completed.

Comment: I think you may have found your problem. "Submit" Your page refreshes and goes back to invisible every-time you click submit.

Comment: submitEmail() is causing a page reload! I didn't notice that! But I don't know why. I'll add my html above.

Comment: I changed the type for the form to "button" instead of submit so that the page doesn't reload. Yet the page keeps reloading. I updated the code above.

Comment: "button" submits the page also. Btw, most people do validation on another event like http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onblur.asp

Comment: I solved it:

Something was reloading the page. After a long time, I figured out that adding the code:

    onsubmit="return false;"

to the <form> would solve the problem. I don't know why but whatever.

Comment: The reason why is because buttons cause the 'form' to submit, which reloads the page. By putting onSubmit="return false;" you turn off this behavior; but there is a caveat to it - that button will never submit anything to server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want your form to ever submit. Then the logical thing to do is to place this little ditty in your form.

```
onsubmit="return false;"
```

Answer (score 0):

This is likely what is happening:

```
function subscribe(){
    //start the loading symbol
    var email = document.getElementById("emailInput").value;
    if (email != "" && email != "Email") {
        submitEmail(); // this fires kicking off a page reload
        success(); // this fire showing the elements before the page is reloaded
    }
    else {
        alert("Input error!"); //input error
    }
};
// once the page is reloaded, the hidden elements are once again not visible
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/jrulle/2V2B4/) to demo the issue

**Resolution**: you need to use [ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8567114/how-to-make-an-ajax-call-without-jquery) to prevent this

Comment: I already have the ajax thing so I'm pretty sure it isn't that.

Comment: No. You didn't get his point, instead of submitting the whole entire page with "Submit" button, use ajax to send the validation.

Comment: Oh I just did this
Something was reloading the page. After a long time, I figured out that adding the code:

    onsubmit="return false;"

to the <form> would solve the problem. I don't know why but whatever.